# Panning UIImageView doesn't remove original image

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have tried both TouchMoves and UIPanGestureRecognizer, my panned image draws to the new location but original image still shows. Sending the setNeedsDisplay to the uiimageview being panned or to the superview also doesn't help. What are my options to solve the situation. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can use, the code will start pan the image in ImageView

```
 @IBAction func startPanning(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        switch sender.state{
        case .began: break

        case .changed:
            imageV.center = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            break


        case .ended: break
        default : break

        }

    }
```

Comment: It doesnt help, @Deepak. Issue lies somewhere else it seems.How I am using panning is, that I have registered the panning on the UIImageView extended class, which responds to the pan gesture. The code is simple as follows: -(void) panHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) recogonizer{
    if(recogonizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
        self.center = [recogonizer translationInView:self.superview];
     }
}

Comment: -(void) initPanGesture{
  self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
   UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureReviews = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panHandler:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureReviews];
}  -(void) panHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) recogonizer{
     if(recogonizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || recogonizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed){
          UIView* v = self.superview;
         self.center = [recogonizer locationInView:v];
     }
 }

Comment: So what really happens is, a class that is extended by UIImageView, has the UIPanGesture as indicated above which now handles the panning message.  The advantage is that if I have hundreds of pins, I will just use the os to handle hit test and message gets handled automatically by the responsible extended uiimageview class.